# How to run my smv file on NuSMV

Tags: model-checking

I have installed NuSMV 2.5.4 on a ubuntu machine. When I run it in interactive mode using the command NuSMV -int first.smv I get the following response cannot open input file first.smv. Why is that? I have placed my smv file(first.smv) in the bin folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `first.smv` should be in the folder that you run the command, not in the `bin` folder

Answer (score 1):

You will need to specify the filepath to "first.smv" such as:

$ NuSMV> read_model -i C:/your folder/first.smv

that will read the model. But Model won't be visible until you give other relevant commands.

HTH